# Handling links in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I'm making an intranet website that is used to link clients to information and files.
I have a JavaScript script that holds all of the links and ID's so I can easily add new links and edit them.
Here is the code for the JS:

```
function set_links()
{
     setHrefById("LinkID1", "link1");
     setHrefById("LinkID2", "link2");
     setHrefById("LinkID3", "link3");
}

function setHrefById(idName. url)
{
    if(document.getElementById(idName))
    {
         document.getElementById(idName).href = url;
    }
}
```

I have the links displaying on the webpage correctly.

Basically, what I want to happen is, when a button is clicked, all of the links to open up at once in new tabs.

Also, how would I be able to automatically add these links onto the webpage. I have to manually add this to the webpage:

```
<A target="_blank" id="LinkID1" href="">Click here</A>
```

Comment: do you mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/fluffydevilbunny/Ljmz6/ make sure your popup blocker is disabled or only one tab will activate (at least in chrome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `window.open` method, and set the `name` argument to `_blank` to open links in a new tab. e.g. `window.open("http://google.com", "_blank")` [See here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

If you just want to store the links in JavaScript and then open them all when a user clicks on a button, why not do something like this:

```
function addListener(element, eventName, handler) {
  if (element.addEventListener) {
    element.addEventListener(eventName, handler, false);
  }
  else if (element.attachEvent) {
    element.attachEvent('on' + eventName, handler);
  }
  else {
    element['on' + eventName] = handler;
  }
}

var links = ["http://google.com", "http://yahoo.com"];
var open_trigger = document.getElementById('open-all');
addListener(open_trigger, "click", function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i ++) {
        window.open(links[i], "_blank");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n3rpq/

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've just tried the window.open method and it didn't work for what I'm looking for. When I click the button, I need it to open all of the links in the JS document. As for where the links are, I need them to be in the JS document and then when I add a new one in, it is automatically generated on the HTML webpage. At the moment, I have to add the link to the JS using setHrefById("LinkID", "link url"); and then add it to the HTML document using <A target="_blank" id="LinkID" href="">Click here</A>. And as for the structure, I only want an Open All button.

Comment: If you only want an open all button then why are you creating the HTML anchor in the first place?

Comment: How about the above? Also, are you using jQuery or not?

Comment: I have 2 pages, one of them has the links using <A target="_blank" id="LinkID" href="">Click here</A>. The second has the button that opens all of the links.

Comment: OK, so you're saying how can you have the links available to **both** pages 1) where the links are visible in the HTML document, and 2) a HTML page which has a button 'click all' which you want to load all of the links from page 1 and open them? That wasn't particularly clear to me from the question! :)

Comment: Also, the script you linked me to only opened up Google, not Yahoo. I'm using Google Chrome, if that's an issue. In response to your comment: all I need help with is the button that opens all of the links that are in the JS document and how I can automatically generate the <A target="_blank" id="LinkID" href="">Click here</A> for each new link I create in the JS document.

Comment: I'm afraid that's a limitation with using JavaScript - Chrome is blocking any additional calls (look at the right of the address bar and you'll see a window with an x in it). I didn't notice this however, as I use Firefox. I checked, and IE10 also seems to limit to 1.

Comment: Ah yes, Chrome was blocking it as a pop-up. So to achieve what I'm looking for I would have to delve into using JQuery or something else?

Comment: I'm afraid not. Chrome is just doing it, because it tries to protect the user. If you were to visit a website a Chrome did nothing when the website tried to open 400 popups, you'd be annoyed. As far as I'm aware, there's no way of subverting this response, maybe if you used flash, but I doubt it again.